# TimeZone computing method

Tags: java, datetime, spring

I feel like there is a code smell in this. Can someone help me to refactor/optimize it?

```
protected TimeZone resolveTimeZone() {
    IUserPreferences preferences = userProfileService.getCurrentUserPreferences();
    if (preferences != null) {
        String timeZone = preferences.getPreferredTimeZone();
        if (timeZone != null && !"".equals(timeZone))
            return TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
        else return defaultTimeZone();
    }
    else return defaultTimeZone();

}

public TimeZone defaultTimeZone() {
    Locale defaultLocale = new Locale(appConfiguration.getDefaultLocale());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(defaultLocale);
    return calendar.getTimeZone();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some immediate improvement ideas are possible at first glance:

- Avoid duplicated code: `defaultTimeZone()` appears twice. It's easy to factor that out by changing the branching logic: keep checking the requirements (`preferences != null`, the preference value not null, and so on) until you find a usable value and return. To handle all other (failure) execution paths, use a single return at the end of the method
- Use the `.isEmpty()` method to check if a string is empty. This is better than `!"".equals(value)`, which means literally "is this value the same as `""`". Using `isEmpty` is natural.
- The variable named `timeZone` suggests it's an instance of `TimeZone`. That's misleading, I would rename it to something else to clarify.

Applying the above:

```
protected TimeZone resolveTimeZone() {
    IUserPreferences preferences = userProfileService.getCurrentUserPreferences();
    if (preferences != null) {
        String timeZoneText = preferences.getPreferredTimeZone();
        if (timeZoneText != null && !timeZoneText.isEmpty()) {
            return TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneText);
        }
    }
    return defaultTimeZone();
}
```

On closer look, there are a few more things I don't really like:

- The `defaultTimeZone` method sticks out a little from other getter calls in the posted code: `getCurrentUserPreferences`, `getPreferredTimeZone`, `getDefaultLocale`, ... Perhaps it would be better to be consistent with those and rename the method to `getDefaultTimeZone`
- Calling `Calendar.getInstance` is costly. If the default timezone will not change during the lifetime of the application, then it would be better to initialize it once during startup, and reuse it afterwards.
- The name `resolveTimeZone` is a bit vague. What does it mean, "resolve", really? Looking at the implementation, it's not as clear as it can be.

I would recommend to split the method like this:

```
protected TimeZone getTimeZone() {
    TimeZone preferredTimeZone = getPreferredTimeZone();
    if (preferredTimeZone != null) {
        return preferredTimeZone;
    }
    return defaultTimeZone();
}

private TimeZone getPreferredTimeZone() {
    IUserPreferences preferences = userProfileService.getCurrentUserPreferences();
    if (preferences != null) {
        String timeZoneText = preferences.getPreferredTimeZone();
        if (timeZoneText != null && !timeZoneText.isEmpty()) {
            return TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneText);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here, the names and implementations of the methods are more natural:

- `getTimeZone`: looking at the implementation it's perfectly clear what's going on: use the preferred timezone if possible, otherwise the default. Nice and simple.
- `getPreferredTimeZone`: from the method name, it comes natural that the method tries to figure out a timezone from the user configuration and return null otherwise.

Alas, this does have the drawback of an extra `if` condition compared to the original. However, the cost of the extra call should be negligible in practice. This may be a matter of taste. I think the value of clarity in the design outweighs the cost of that extra `if` (unless performance is absolutely critical, of course).

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite `resolveTimeZone` like this:

```
protected TimeZone resolveTimeZone() {
    IUserPreferences preferences = userProfileService.getCurrentUserPreferences();
    if (preferences != null) {
        String timeZone = preferences.getPreferredTimeZone();
        if (timeZone != null && !timeZone.equals("")) {
            return TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);     
        }  
    }
    return defaultTimeZone();
}
```

Notice the fact that I removed the `else` branch from the innermost `if`. It was not needed. In case the timezone check fails, the function will return at the last `return` statement anyway.

I also replaced the yoda conditional there. I personally dislike yoda conditionals, and I believe they do not add any sort of value, especially in your case. `timeZone.equals("")` is read as "timezone equals empty string" whereas `"".equals(timeZone)` is read as "empty string equals timeZone". Logically equivalent since equality is commutative, but the second version is hardly natural for most people.

I also removed the empty line before the last brace. It kinda showed a lack of attention to detail, and it broke the rather consistent code surrounding it. I guess it's safe to say it was the first code smell I spotted.

I have no big issues with `defaultTimeZone()`. Perhaps the fact that the name would be more appropriate for a field, rather than a function performing an action?

All of the above aside, your code is quite clean and easy to parse.

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of taste, but at lesst less errorprone, but you should consider using braces `{}` for single `if` statements too.

That beeing said, let us face the `resolveTimeZone()` method.

The else part can be removed completly, because if the condition evaluates to true it won' t be reached.

The method can be refactored to

```
protected TimeZone resolveTimeZone() {
    IUserPreferences preferences = userProfileService.getCurrentUserPreferences();
    if (preferences != null) {
        String timeZone = preferences.getPreferredTimeZone();
        if (timeZone != null && !"".equals(timeZone)){
            return TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
        }
    }
    return defaultTimeZone();
}
```